# Sort packages without adding/updating dependencies

Tags: composer-php

On an existing project with a long list of packages and various feature branches where new dependencies are being added I want to mitigate and minimize merge conflicts by adding dependencies in alphabetical order.

To get this cleaned up, though, I'd like to be able to run the `--sort-packages` functionality on its own -- without adding or updating anything -- as just a single commit that cleans up the existing packages, and then add `"sort-packages" : "true"` to the `"config"` section of the composer.json file to ensure all new packages are added in alphabetical order going forward.

**Is it possible to sort the packages listed in a messy `composer.json` file using composer's `--sort-packages` option on the CLI without actually adding or updating any dependencies?**

The only workaround I've found so far is to run composer update some/package --sort-packages  against a package that you're sure wont update because it is already at the latest version. This is not ideal.

Comment: You can always do `composer require` for a small and pretty stable package, like `psr/log` for example.

Comment: note that, when you do `composer require --dev` it will only sort dev dependencies and `composer require` will only sort regular dependencies

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can "re-require" a package you've already required. In my case, it's Symfony 3.4, so I did:

```
composer require symfony/symfony:3.4.*
```

If you don't have `"sort-packages": true` in your composer.json, you can do:

```
composer require --sort-packages symfony/symfony:3.4.*
```

From what I can tell, only the require command has the option for sorting packages so it seems you need to require a package for sorting to be applied.

---

It is since [1.0.0-alpha10 - released 2015-04-14](https://getcomposer.org/changelog/1.0.0-alpha10) - that `composer require` has the `--sort-packages` option:

> - Added --sort-packages option to `require` command for sorting dependencies

This is not yet the `composer.json#/config/sort-packages` which is since [1.0.0-beta1 - released 2016-03-03](https://getcomposer.org/changelog/1.0.0-beta1), roughly a year later:

> - Added `sort-packages` config option [[#4715](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4715)] to force sorting of the requirements when using the `require` command

It stems from [pull-request #3549](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/3549) and there is also a bit of backstory as well as more options discussed in [*Normalizing composer.json* by
Andreas Möller (localheinz), Jan 2018](https://localheinz.com/articles/2018/01/15/normalizing-composer.json/).

Answer (score 47):

To quote from [the Composer manual "Config" section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#sort-packages):

> #### sort-packages
>
> Defaults to `false`. If `true`, the `require` command keeps packages sorted by name in composer.json when adding a new package.

So if you run

```bash
composer config sort-packages true
```

you command Composer to add the following to your `composer.json` file:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

The next time you do a `composer require <vendor-name>/<project-name>[:<version-constraint>[@<stability-flag>]]` it will automatically sort the whole list. You can ["re-require"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241608/367456) a configured package – one that is already required by the root package, cf. *composer-show(1) w/ --installed* – to only sort the existing list of dependencies without additional changes, see as well [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241608/367456) by [Darryl Hein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5441/darryl-hein) about this and more information.

---

### Change the Default `sort-packages` Value (`false`)

The setting can also be configured globally:

```bash
composer config --global sort-packages true
```

In which case the `$COMPOSER_HOME/config.json` will be altered, instead of the project-level `composer.json` file, the root package or configuration.

**Note:** The root configuration supersedes the global configuration for this `sort-packages` setting as long as it is not unset:

```bash
composer config --unset sort-packages
```

For [the change log see the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241608/367456) by [Darryl Hein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5441/darryl-hein).

Comment: This is indeed the first step, but the act of adding this to the JSON file doesn't have any effect on actually sorting the previously unsorted packages.   (This answer just restates something I've already stated in the original question).  The question that needs to be answered here is specific to the second step, i.e., after adding `"sort-packages": true` to the JSON file how do you get composer to apply the sort without adding or updating any packages?

Comment: I guess I should have added to my original post, that after adding this to composer.json, it will automatically sort the whole list, the next time you do a composer require...

In case you need it to sort now, then you could add a random dependency and remove it again ;-)

Comment: Instead of editing your `composer.json` directly, I would recommend doing it via the CLI to prevent a possible wrong edit and this can be faster to write too. Simply write: `composer config sort-packages true`.

Comment: @StefanKorfitz I edited your answer to reflect your "I guess I should have" comment and Robin Bastiaan's suggestion (you really should avoid encouraging the anti-pattern of manually editing config files touched and maintained by tools ;-)

Comment: @StefanKorfitz actually doing a ```composer update``` after having added the ```composer config sort-packages true``` doesn't work. But running a ```composer require vendor\package``` does work.

Comment: @Potherca: Can you provide reference with wich Composer version composer-update(1) did sort packages for you? In the meantime I've removed that part from the answer I can find no reference at all for that.

Comment: @hakre It indeed looks like this functionality was removed after v1 of composer. The `reuire` command seems to be the only one that actually sorts the list. 

I've updated the answer to reflect your comment. 

Answer (score 0):

First of all, +1 for using `"sort-packages": true`, for all the reasons you describe.

It is a bad idea to edit `composer.lock` directly, but I do not think the same applies to `composer.json`. I would edit the files in Vim, select everything inside the `"require"` and `"require-dev"` sections (one at a time) and `:sort`. Plus some fiddling to make sure that every line except the last has a comma.